# Use different nuGet packages.config based on build configuration

Tags: nuget, buildconfiguration

Lets say we want two configurations.

Configuration A 'BuildForCustomerA' is a solution with a reference to MySharedLibrary v1.1.

Configuration B is a solution with a reference to MySharedLibrary v1.3.

Is there a way to have Configuration A point to 'packages.ConfigA.config' and Configuration B point to 'packages.ConfigB.config', (or any functionally similar setup), so that they can peg different internal and third party references correctly using nuget and package restore?

thanks for reading

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?